# Как отобразить текст который был создан WYSIWYG редактором?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wysiwyg

Использую WYSIWYG редактор summernote,   в админ панеле благодаря редактору создаю текст (описание продукта), этот текст хранится в базе данных.

Посетители сайта должны увидеть описание продукта,  текст извлекается из базы данных но  отображается неправильно(в нем много&nbsp знаков),

Как  отобразить текст, который был создан  WYSIWYG  редактором и сохранен в базе данных ?

Comment: Если мешает `&nbsp` перед добавление в базу замените его на пробел или пустоту `$string = str_ireplace('&nbsp', ' ', $string)` - это если не хочется копаться в настройках `WYSIWYG`

Comment: Проблема не только в пробеле , проблема в том что,    WYSIWYG  редактор помогает создать красивый текст, но как извлечь  этот текст ,   чтобы он также красиво отображался ?

Comment: Как текст попадает в базу данных, как извлекаете, как отображаете? Слишком мало подробностей